# (terminal) rails console how to add ascii caracters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal, ascii

On rails console I'm trying to query :

`@reunions = Activite.where(:type_activite => "Réunion")`

but it will remove the '`é`' in the console like

```
  Activite Load (21.4ms)  SELECT `activites`.* FROM `activites` WHERE `activites`.`type_activite` = 'Runion'
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

In my model I have this:

```
class Activite < ActiveRecord::Base
    ACTIVITE = ['Réunion', 'Chorale']
end
```

View (form)

```
<%= select("post", "activite", Activite::ACTIVITE, {include_blank: true}) %>
```

In my Form  I'm using a select and it looks ok but when I submit the form it will chop any ascii caracters, how can I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

- specify an encoding. Your `application.rb` should have something like this at the top `config.encoding = "utf-8"`.
- In your `database.yml` make sure you set the config encoding. This is what it looks like for MySQL.

  ```
  development:
      adapter: mysql
      encoding: utf8
      database: my_international_db
      username: user
      password: password
      socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  ```
- You may need to restart your database manually after making changes.
- If this doesn't work you might try reinstalling ruby with readline support. This link works if you're using RVM: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1016